# Initialize a entity manager for scale in JAX-RS

Tags: java, database, jpa, jax-rs, entitymanager

---

I'm using a JAX-RS RESTful Service deployed in heroku. This service only retrieves information or insert into the DB. Each time a thread is started I execute the following code to create the entity manager:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    try {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersistenceUnit", System.getProperties());
        //InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
        entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I think this code makes my app not scalable. Does anybody knows other way to initialize the entity manager?

pd: I'm using a jetty-embedded server in heroku.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your EntityManagerFactory should only be initialized once and reused since it is expensive to create.  The EntityManagerFactory is also thread safe. You can make a static instance of EntityManagerFactory (such as by creating a singleton class to store it). You can then call your getInstance method whenever you need to create an EntityManager instance

Example singleton:

```
public class Emf {

  private static Emf theInstance = null;
  private  EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = null;

  private Emf() {
      try {
           entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersistenceUnit", System.getProperties());
           //InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
          } catch (Exception e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
    }

  public static synchronized Emf getInstance() {
      if (theInstance == null) {
        theInstance = new Emf();
     }
      return theInstance;
   }

  public EntityManagerFactory getFactory() {
  return entityManagerFactory;
}
```

}

Call it like this:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
   try {
      entityManager = Emf.getInstance().getFactory().createEntityManager();
  } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me that in a simple example please?

Comment: @user3700763 Not the best example of a singleton but simple for demonstration purposes - let me know if you would like a better example

Comment: of course! if do you have a better example please put it here!

Comment: of course! if do you have a better example please put it here!